# Wpf binding with nested properties

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, listbox

**ViewModel**

I have a property of type **Member** called **KeyMember**. The **'Member'** type has an **ObservableCollection** called **Addresses**. The **Address** is composed of two strings - **street** and **postcode** .

**View**

I have a ListBox whose item source need to be set to ViewModels's **KeyMember** property and it should display the **Street** of all the Past Addresses in the Address collection.

**Question**

My ViewModel and View relationship is established properly.

I am able to write a data template for the above simple case as below

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding KeyMember.Addresses}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="Address">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Street}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I am curios to know how to write the DataTemplate if I change **KeyMember** from type **Member** to **ObservableCollection< Member >** assuming that the collection has only one element. I am not sure whether this is a valid scenrio and it's implementation feasibility.

PS: I know that for multiple elements in collection, I will have to implement the **Master-Detail pattern/scenario**. I am looking into this at the moment.

Comment: I'm a little confused.  Why would you implement a one-element collection, instead of simply implementing INotifyPropertyChanged?  Is it just a "implementation step" geared towards eventually handing an actual collection of 0 to n elements?

Are you guaranteeing that the collection will always hold exactly one element?

Comment: I am learning data Binding. I am not maintaining one element collection. I am just curios to know whether we can bind in such scenario or the scenario is invalid. Assuming there is always only one element in the collection, can we data bind?

For my actual scenario there are zero or more elements in the collection and I am working on master-detail pattern this. I have  successfully implemented INotifyPropertyChanged and used CollectionViewSource where necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to bind to the 0th element, you can do `{Binding Path=[0].Addresses}`, and likewise for any other elements in a collection that supports array-style indexing. I agree with Wonko though that this is a rather unusual requirement.

Comment: JustABill,

Thank you for the reply. As I mentioned earlier this is not a requirement for my work. This question is more on lines of curiosity. Being a novice, bindings like {Binding Path=[0].Addresses} is something new that I didn't know and is exactly what I wanted to know - whether explicityly binding to a particular element in collection is possible or not. Ofcourse I would not be using this in my work as I will not explicitly bind to a particular element from collection. But it's always good to know what is possible even when, in practice, it might not be the best thing to do.

Comment: Ah, curiosity is fine. You'll see the [0] in Binding Paths commonly when you get to validation - it's a common (but poor) way to retrieve the current error message. Both in that specific case and possibly in yours, if the collection is ever null you should not do this because trying to get the [0] element from a null collection will make WPF throw an exception, which you won't see but which will slow down your program.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any online resource where I can read advance data binding techniques?

Comment: I'm not aware of anything specific to recommend, but most of the fun stuff I've seen involves the RelativeSource parameter. So you can (to use a stupid example) make a UserControl the same background color as that of its parent Window. So maybe look at that.